# App is not retrieving data from Firebase into Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

the app is not working and always gets stopped on emulator and on the real device and also not retrieving data from firebase database.
on phone it just shows app stops while as it works a little n emulator but not retrieves data.

```
09-04 11:32:06.674 21301-24890/com.food.dany.danaerys D/FA: Connected to 
remote service
09-04 11:32:06.674 21301-24890/com.food.dany.danaerys V/FA: Processing 
queued up service tasks: 3
09-04 11:32:07.197 21301-21301/com.food.dany.danaerys W/art: Before Android 
 4.1, method int 
android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, 
boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in 
android.widget.ListView
09-04 11:32:07.199 21301-21301/com.food.dany.danaerys I/Choreographer: 
Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main 
thread.
09-04 11:32:07.214 21301-21333/com.food.dany.danaerys D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dd70000: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9dd73fd0)
09-04 11:32:07.862 21301-21301/com.food.dany.danaerys I/Choreographer: 
Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main 
thread.
09-04 11:32:08.019 21301-21301/com.food.dany.danaerys 
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
09-04 11:32:11.747 21301-24890/com.food.dany.danaerys V/FA: Inactivity, 
disconnecting from the service
```

an this is my java code below and when i retrieve the data from database it shows blank screen and retrieves nothing from firebase.

```
    package com.food.dany.danaerys;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.food.dany.danaerys.Common.Common;
import com.food.dany.danaerys.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.food.dany.danaerys.ViewHolder.MenuViewHolder;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;

    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //init firebase
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category=database.getReference("category");



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        //set name for user
        View headerView=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtFullName=(TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
        txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());

        //load menu
recycler_menu=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadMenu();

    }

    private void loadMenu() {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
               viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.imageView);

                final Category clickItem=model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this,""+clickItem.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: add rules in firebase for retrive data from database.

Comment: Already done that

Comment: u getting any error?

Comment: Not getting error app neither retreiving data from firebase and gets stopped

Comment: put log of app when its crash or run

Comment: Check my question have put it already

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/       check this link and  put code in your app as per given link. its work fine

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri, share your database structure from where you are retrieving data.

Comment: Maddy https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3E4UVMeBpHGUjY2M2YyYURzRTA/view?usp=drivesdk